# Php $_POST[] method not working with certain input name

Tags: php

I am working on a form and it looks like this

```
<form name="project" method="post" action="result.php">
   Address: <input name="address[line1]" type="text"/>
</form>
```

In the result.php, I use the following code to get the input

```
<?php echo (isset ($_POST['address[line1]') ?  $_POST ['address [line1]'] : 'fail') ?>
```

However, I keep getting 'fail' on my page instead of catching the input address[line1], and the strange thing is when I change the name to "addressLine1" it works perfectly, can anyone advise me on this?

I am new to web development and I am pretty confused now.

Comment: Brackets `[]` are used for arrays. Plus, you're missing an `if` for your `isset`.

Comment: Thanks! Also just realize this by googling around! BTW, my isset works and I work this out by referring to http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples, any issue with this? @Fred

Answer (score 4):

what you are after is `$_POST["address"]["line1"]` the array notation in the field name results in an array being created on the PHP side. In the future you can always just `var_dump` or `print_r` the contents of `$_POST` to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks so much. var_dump is quite useful!